# How do I execute an Ant command if a task fails?

Tags: java, ant

Suppose I have some Ant task - say javac or junit - if either task fails, I want to execute a task, but if they succeed I don't.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your [junit](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) target, for example, you can set the `failureProperty`:

```
<target name="junit" depends="compile-tests" description="Runs JUnit tests">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.report}"/>
    <junit printsummary="true" failureProperty="test.failed">
        <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="${test.class}" todir="${junit.report}" if="test.class"/>
        <batchtest fork="true" todir="${junit.report}" unless="test.class">
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
                <exclude name="**/AllTests.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Then, create a target that only runs if the `test.failed` property is set, but fails at the end:

```
<target name="otherStuff" if="test.failed">
    <echo message="I'm here. Now what?"/>
    <fail message="JUnit test or tests failed."/>
</target>
```

Finally, tie them together:

```
<target name="test" depends="junit,otherStuff"/>
```

Then just call the `test` target to run your JUnit tests. The `junit` target will run. If it fails (failure or error) the `test.failed` property will be set, and the body of the `otherStuff` target will execute.

The [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task supports `failonerror` and `errorProperty` attributes, which can be used to get similar behavior.

Answer (score 6):

as mentioned from Kai:

> [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) has a trycatch task.

But you need the recent version 1.0b3. And then use

```
<trycatch>
    <try>
        ... <!-- your executions which may fail -->
    </try>
    <catch>
        ... <!-- execute on failure -->
        <throw message="xy failed" />
    </catch>
</trycatch>
```

The trick is to throw an error again to indicate a broken build.

Answer (score 1):

[ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) has a trycatch task.

Answer (score 0):

Set a property in the task for which you want to check for failure, and then write the second task so that it executes if the property is not set. I don't remember the exact syntaxes for build.xml, or I'd give examples.